# Как предоставить пользователю выбор перехода по ссылке?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как предоставить пользователю выбор перехода по ссылке ?

Когда пользователя нажимает на ссылку, должно появляться окно с двумя кнопками "да" и "нет". При нажатии "да" пользователь переходит по ссылке, при нажатии "нет" не переходит.

```
<a href="tip.html">Перейти</a>
```

Можно конечно сделать впереди div с z-index, и когда мы наживаем на него, эмулируем нажание на тег `<a>` но это мне не очень нравится.
Может быть есть еще какой-нибудь способ?

Comment: Автор мог выбрать любой ответ в одну строчку, но выбрал самый длинный, ещё и на jquery. Вы, походу, из дома без фреймворков не выходите

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jquery версия

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').on('click', function(event) {
    if (confirm('Перейти?') === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://ya.ru">Ссылка</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
$('.yes-no').on('click',function(e){
 $('.window').addClass('window_show');
});

$('.window').on('click','a', function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('yes')){
   return true;
  }
  else{
   $('.window').removeClass('window_show');
    e.preventDefault()
  }
});
```

```css
.window{
  display: none;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.window_show{
  display: block;
}
.window a{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="yes-no" href="#">Перейти</a>
<div class="window">
  <a class="yes" href="tip.html">Да</a>  
  <a class="no" href="#">Нет</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `return true` немного лишний.

Answer (score 4):

Можно вот так, без сторонних библиотек, ловить все клики в документе, и на клики по ссылкам выводить диалог «Переходить?»:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if( e.target.nodeName !== 'A') return true;
  return confirm("Перейти?");
});
```

```html
<a href="http://ya.ru" target="_blank">Перейти</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<a onclick='if(confirm("Перейти?")) window.location.href = "tip.html";'>Перейти</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
 <a href="https://google.com" onclick="return confirm('Перейти по ссылке?');">Перейти</a>
```

Comment: Самый лучший вариант. `return true`, либо `return false` по клику